# How to disable button when corresponding page is opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I have a button which opens a page in new tab. On button click, the page is opened on new page and the button should be disabled. When the user closes the tab, I want to enable the button. Is there any way I could do this in jquery or javascript? I have searched the web but no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptual idea would be to maintain a reference to the opened window in outer context (module or global variable), so that it can be easily accessed from your code. Here is the example:

```
var windowsArray = [];

function addWindowInTab() {
    var newWindow = window.open('page.html', '_newtab'); 
    windowsArray[windowsArray.length] = newWindow;
    newWindow.onunload=enableButton;
}

function removeWindowTab(newWindow){
  var idx = array.indexOf(newWindow);
  if(idx != -1) {
    windowsArray.splice(idx, 1);
  }
}

function enableButton(){
  $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
}

//somewhere in MVC page
$(function(){
  $("#buttonOpenWindow").click(function(){
     addWindowInTab();
  });
  //later, when a button should be disabled...
  if (windowsArray.length){
    $("#myButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

Note also, that here you can perform some more advanced checks, such as if window with particular name is opened or if multiple windows are opened. Bear in mind that in order to open a new tab, the AddWindowInTab function must be called in response to user action, such as pressing Ctrl+ clicking the left mouse button

Comment: thank Borys,but how enable and disable button on corresponding  tab open and  close